# Accessing the Data Source of a Control

Tags: mvc

I have a control property with a data source pointing to a folder with items with fields.

Is there a way to loop through the children of the item in the data source and display them on my view?

In my view I have:

```cs
@using Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation
@using Sitecore.Mvc
@model RenderingModel
```

In my controller I have:

```cs
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var renderingModel = new Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.RenderingModel();
    var myTitle = renderingModel.PageItem.Fields["Title"].Value;
    var item = Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.RenderingContext.Current.Rendering.Item;
    var itemPageContext = Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.RenderingContext.Current.PageContext.Item;
    return View();
}
```

[image: Control Properties]

[image]

Answer (score 26, accepted):

**Controller:**

```cs
public class RotatorController : SitecoreController 
{
  public ActionResult Index()
  {
    var dataSourceId = RenderingContext.CurrentOrNull.Rendering.DataSource;
    var dataSource = Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem(dataSourceId);

    var viewModel = new RotatorViewModel
    {
      RotatorItems = dataSource.Children
    };
    return View(viewModel);
  }
}
```

**View Model:**

```cs
public class RotatorViewModel
{
  public IEnumerable<Item> RotatorItems { get; set; }
}
```

**View:**

```razor
@model RotatorViewModel 

<h1>This is a rotator!</h1>
@foreach (var item in Model.RotatorItems)
{
  <h2>@item.Fields["Title"]</h2>
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to change your model on the view **@model RotatorViewModel**

Comment: Nice catch. Done.

Answer (score 5):

Since you have `@model RenderingModel`, you could access the datasource item via `Model.Rendering.Item`.  To loop over the child items of the datasource you would do something like this:

```cs
@foreach(Item child in Model.Rendering.Item.Children)
{
    <div>@child.Name</div>
}
```

Comment: This code has a red line under .Name. Cannot convert method group Name to non-delegate type object.

Comment: You may need to be explict with the type of `child` and use `Item` rather than `var`.  I updated the answer to show this.

Comment: Your answer seems to work for accessing the DataSource item. One difference though is that if no DataSource has been set, accessing `Model.Rendering.Item` resolves to the context item while `Model.Rendering.DataSource` will just be empty.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```c#
Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.RenderingContext.Current.Rendering.DataSource
```

You will get your datasource item (Home Page Rotator) ID.

Then you can obtain children and pass whole collection to the View via Model and display whatever you want.

Comment: How do I obtain the children?

Answer (score 0):

I access a Data Source which is a folder of content items having a Name field and a Price field.  In the View Rendering, my Data Source is set to /sitecore/content/Products which is the folder containing the projects.  In my View Rendering cshtml file I have the following:

```
@using Sitecore.Data.Items
@using Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation

<table>
    @foreach (Item product in RenderingContext.Current.Rendering.Item.Children)
     {
        <tr><td>@product["Name"]</td><td>@product["Price"]</td></tr>
     }
</table>
```

This accesses the data source in a simpler way.  This is with Sitecore 9.